# python server for real time telemetry: how to skip packets to avoid "falling behind"

Tags: python, multicast, recv

I've got a real-time telemetry problem I'd like guidance on. The basics are obvious: a stream of UDP multicast packets are arriving at a given address/port. msg = recv(), then decode and display that msg, and all's well. But what if the next packet arrives before the first msg has been fully processed, or worse, what if the next TWO packets have arrived before we've gotten back to the recv() loop? Since this is a real-time telemetry situation, I'd like to (a) recognize that there's more than one packet to be dealt with, and then (b) delete/ignore all packets that in the multicast reception buffer except for the most recent.

I have spent a few hours trying to get recv() to work in a non-blocking mode and to return a status showing how many separate packets are in the received multicast queue, to no avail.

I'm using matplotlib/tkinter for the display of the data, that (plus hey, it's Python) is why operating on each packet is a lengthy operation.

Am I way off in the weeds here? Is there a better approach?

Comment: "multicast reception buffer" - if you don't have time to process what's in the buffer, don't buffer it, or buffer no more than a single packet. Apparently, you just want to throw away anything older in the buffer anyway. If you do still want to register that there have been packets missed, you can create a buffer that remembers overwriting itself until it is read.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Fair point. I didn't see a way to extract the code in a compact way, so tried to rely on my description. I have since become convinced that it's a losing battle to try to wrestle Linux for control of whatever buffer it uses for incoming multicast packets. Instead, my new plan is to put the recv() loop in its own thread, and queue its output to the display thread. The display thread can keep popping the queue until the most recent packet is the only one left. Wish me luck.